# Sort sheets in vba depending on the last characters of their names

Tags: excel, sorting, tabs

I have a workbook with multiple sheets having the following names (SSI_21_AB, SSI_22_BC, SSI_19_CD,  SSI_20_AC, FFI_20_AL). I want to sort them by the last two characters to look like this ( SSI_21_**AB**, SSI_20_**AC**, SSI_22_**BC**, SSI_19_**CD**)

This is what I have so far but it doesn't quite work, so I will appreciate your help :)

```
Sub SortSheetTabsAscending()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
     If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "SSI" Then
        If Split("_", Sheets(j).Name)(0) + 0 > Split("_", Sheets(j + 1).Name)(0) + 0 Then
            Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
        End If
     End If
    Next j
Next i
ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "but it doesn't quite work" isn't very specific. What exactly is the problem? You don't say what should happen to sheets whose name doesn't start with `SSI`

Comment: It gives me a syntax error at second `IF`. Also I want to take in consideration only SSI category,

Comment: Split results in an array (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)). Try using `Right(Sheets(j).Name, 2)` instead of the Split since those are the characters you want to compare

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thank you so much!